# Why does some files miss when committed to Subversion?

Tags: html, css, web, svn, version-control

I am developing a website for a company. However some of the css attributes which are in my project goes missing when I commit my code to the subversion repository.

So in the other end when my team mates access it, the attributes goes missing. I reassured that it was not a mistake when I commit. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion commits are atomic and consistent. If some files are missing, then they were not included in your commit or were not even added to your working copy with the `svn add` command.

When you put new files to your working copy, you first need to tell Subversion client to begin tracking them, i.e. add them to the working copy. You need to do this using the [`svn add`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/add/) command.

Before you commit, you need to examine the status of your working copy with the [`svn status`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/status/) command. It will help you find out whether there are any unversioned files or irrelevant changes.

Read [SVNBook | Basic Work Cycle](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/).